# Cell spacing in UICollectionView minimumInteritemSpacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

How to do set cell spacing in a section of UICollectionView?  UICollectionView there is a property `minimumInteritemSpacing`, I need to set  1.0 still it not work. And I implemented the delegate method.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
  {
     return 1.0;
  }
```

Comment: What the result you have with this?

Answer (score 12):

To check about how your collection Cells would look, you can try this in your Storyboard with the help of storyboard. First just for the sake of checking, put some static cells in your CollectionViewController like this so that your screen appears like this :

[image]

No you can see those cells and the spacing between them. In your case, the cells will appear with improper spacing as you have shown above. So now open with this screen open, open up the Size Inspector fron your Interface Builder. It would look something like this :

[image]

Now you can see some options in the size inspector window. You can adjust the size of each cell and also the spacing between them using the Min. Spacing option. And finally for equal spacing from left and right sides, use the Section Insets Option. As you change the values there, the change will be reflected in your Controller View. So you can get an idea if you want to increase/decrease some values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Every upvoted answer on SO related to cell spacing basically comes down to randomly changing and trying to guess the various delegate method return values. This is by far the fastest and easiest way to figure out what values you need.

Answer (score 4):

you can set programmatically like this

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
contestsCollectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Answer (score 3):

This method set up spaces between cells, footer and header:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the space between cells (minimumInteritemSpacing) but the insets of the collection view.